# TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' to a list

Tags: python

here is my list that I made:

```
nums= []
for n in range(10):
    thenums= random.randint(10,90)
    print(thenums, end= " ")
    nums.append(thenums)
```

and now I need help writing each integer separately, but I am having an issue writing each number from the list on an individual line on a file.

```
with open("angles.txt", 'w') as h:
    for n in nums:
        h.write[str(n), + '\n']
```

Comment: `h.write[str(n), + '\n']` or `h.write(str(n) + '\n')`?

Comment: The square brackets (`[]`) are used for _list indexing_, not function calls, so your `h.write[` is nonsense. What's more, `str(n),+'\n'` is a SyntaxError, you're appending `'\n'` to __what__?

Comment: I am using the '\n' to create another line after each integer. I believe...

Comment: ok understood, thanks for the help Kevin

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is quite far of. The line

```
h.write[str(n), + '\n']
```

produces a tuple of two elements, `str(n)` and `+ '\n'`; the latter throws your exception:

```
>>> + '\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Without the comma you correctly concatenate the number and the string:

```
>>> n = 42
>>> str(n) + '\n'
'42\n'
```

but then you are also trying to use `h.write` like it is a list or dictionary:

```
>>> h = open('/tmp/demo.txt', 'w')
>>> h.write['42\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Use `(...)` parentheses to call something; the correct expression is:

```
h.write(str(n) + '\n')
```

Comment: the comma was the issue after changing the square bracelets.